# how add icon in toolbarItem in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My xamarin android project does not have Drawawble folders under Resources, I haveI'm trying to set icon for a toolbar item in shared project. If I set an image as embedded resource I should be able to access it from the shared project, am I wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
x:Class="BoringAppUi.MainPage" Title="Main Page">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Logout" Clicked="OnLogoutButtonClicked" Order="Primary"  Priority="0"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Home" Icon="@mipmap/baseline_home_blue_48.png" Clicked="OnHomeIconClicked" Order="Primary" Priority="1"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Main app content goes here" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You have to put the drawable in the android project to display the icon.

Comment: Assuming "baseline_home_blue_48.png" is a black or white image in the android mipmap folder structure, try removing "@mipmap/" from the xamarin.forms Icon value.

Comment: Create a folder `Drawable` in your android project . It is an existing issue of IDE .

Answer (score 3):

You also need to create the Folder Resources and Drawable to add Images.
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5v8G.png)

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Logout" Clicked="OnLogoutButtonClicked" Order="Primary"  Priority="0"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Home" Icon="baselinehomeblue48.png" Clicked="OnHomeIconClicked" Order="Primary" Priority="1"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is xaml based code *<ToolbarItem Name="iconexample" Icon="icon.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="Onclick" />*
```

and  C#  based code
    *new ToolbarItem () { Icon = "icon.png"}*